# yii2 number max, min with dot and comma validation

Tags: php, validation, yii2, price

In my script I need validate price with comma and dot and max and min value. 
This is my rule()

```
return [
        [['price'], 'required', 'message' => 'Price ...'],
        [['price'], 'number', 'numberPattern' => '/^[0-9]{1,2}([\.,][0-9]{1,2})*$/',
            'message' => 'Price ...', 'max' => 25, min => '0'],
    ];
```

It works good when I put price like 25.00 (. dot) but when I put 25,01 (, comma) validate don't work. Do you have any idea how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this solution to be working well with all inputs and you don't need to look for specific widget options. In your **View** file (at the bottom preferred) register JS:

```
$this->registerJs("        
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('keyup', 'input', function(e){
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[,]/g, '.'));
        });
    });
");
```

This will change all **commas** to **dots** in all inputs. I have tested myself (of course) and it's working well.

If you, however, want to change in a way that **only in some inputs** this should be applied, you'll have to add a custom class to each of them and then slightly change this code to:

```
$this->registerJs("        
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('keyup', '.CustomClassName', function(e){
            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[,]/g, '.'));
        });
    });
");
```

I think it's better than using options for widgets since you will be required to find such one (you don't even know if this option even exists in the first place) while this one will always exists as long as you don't forget to add custom class and register this JavaScript code.

Comment: thank you! This works well but I had to remove $this->registerJs(" ");

Comment: @Damian I see. Well, I'm glad that worked well, too!